# How to animate height of UIDatePickerView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation, hidden

I have static `UITableViewCell` with a hidden `datePickerView` in it. When a `button` gets selected, the `datePickerView` becomes visible, and the `cells` height becomes bigger. Here is the code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        if (self.datePickerView.hidden == YES) {
            return 252 - self.datePickerView.bounds.size.height;
        }
        else return 252;
    }
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150;
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (IBAction)datePicker:(id)sender
{
    if (self.datePickerView.hidden == YES)
    {
        [self.datePickerView setHidden:NO];

        [self.datePickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.datePickerView.frame.origin.x, self.datePickerView.frame.origin.y, self.datePickerView.frame.size.width, 0)];
        [UIDatePicker animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^(){
            [self.datePickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.datePickerView.frame.origin.x, self.datePickerView.frame.origin.y, self.datePickerView.frame.size.width, self.datePickerView.frame.size.height)];
        }];
    } else {
        [self.datePickerView setHidden:YES];
    }
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

When the `datePickerView` becomes visible, and the `cells` height gets bigger, the `cells` height animates, but the `datePickerView` doesn't. I tried to animate its height so it should be synced with the `cell`, but it's not?

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting `datePickerView`'s frame in animation, you are not changing it at all. Try this instead:

```
CGFloat originalHeight = self.datePickerView.frame.size.height;
[self.datePickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.datePickerView.frame.origin.x, self.datePickerView.frame.origin.y, self.datePickerView.frame.size.width, 0)];
[UIDatePicker animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^(){
    [self.datePickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.datePickerView.frame.origin.x, self.datePickerView.frame.origin.y, self.datePickerView.frame.size.width, originalHeight)];
}];
```

Comment: It still doesn't animate?

Comment: After animation is its height '0' or expected value?

Comment: expected value. The height never shows a value of 0